# Combining query results of two different tables

Tags: sql, mysql

First select query

> Table 1:

```
ID   Value
131  ABC
120  DEF
```

Second select query

> ```
> Table 2:
> ```

```
ID 
120
131
```

I want to write a single query which will fetch me combining two tables (the required output)

```
ID Value
120 DEF
131 ABC
```

**Note**: if there is no entry in Table2, return the data from Table1 else combine and return the result.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Which SQL database are you using?

Comment: are you talking about linQ , SQL , ... ? what is your data source ?

Comment: I missed to add this line, if there is no entry in Table 2, return the data from table 1 else combine and return the result. I am using mysql 5.0, i need using a direct SQL query.

Comment: pls edit this information in the original question, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

if it can't find the matching record in table2 it will fill table2 columns in the result set with null

Comment: Thanks.Where does it check for entry is in table 2 & then make a decision?

Comment: the join condition is doing that (table1.ID = table2.ID) , and the fact that it's a left join even if it couldn't find ID in table2 it would return data from table1

Comment: Thanks for the query, there are two answers which are correct here & i picked the underneath one as it consumes less time to return the query.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 - there should not be any difference (performance) between using Left join and Left Outer Join and also using aliases !!! as you can see in one the comments . the only difference here is I answered your question and then someone copied my answer with a little change to syntax and you accepted that answer !!! anyway happy that ur problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1,Table2 WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, value
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Is there any difference between in output for  LEFT OUTER JOIN  vs LEFT JOIN.